# Replace all tables of a database except one, with data from another db

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, database-restore

I have a Django app, the database for which is under active manual development (it's a language-learning app, so it stores vocabulary, grammatical concepts, etc). I'd prefer to do that development in my local django/postgres environment.

However, I don't want to be constantly wiping out the User table from the live version!

I'm very new to Postgres, so please don't assume I know what I'm doing here - would some kind of schema be the right approach here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To just backup the one table, use [`COPY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-copy.html) from inside the database:

```
COPY user_tbl TO '/path/to/file';
```

or [`pg_dump`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-pgdump.html) from the shell:

```
pg_dump -t user_tbl mydb > user_tbl.sql
```

Then drop the database, restore your new version, empty `user_tbl` and use `COPY FROM` to restore the one table:

```
COPY user_tbl FROM  '/path/to/file';
```

or restore the backup with the one table from the shell with [`psql`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-psql.html):

```
psql -f user_tbl.sql mydb
```

### Identify depending tables

#### Quick and dirty

There is no such thing as "COPY ... CASCADE". The simplest method to identify depending tables would be to start a transaction, call `TRUNCATE tbl CASCADE` and record the notices you get:

```
BEGIN;
TRUNCATE user_tbl CASCADE;

NOTICE:  truncate cascades to table "tbl1"
NOTICE:  truncate cascades to table "tbl2"
NOTICE:  truncate cascades to table "tbl3"
```

Then roll back the transaction - so nothing actually changes:

```
ROLLBACK;
```

Careful with that. If you `COMMIT` the truncate goes through.

#### Slow and sure

Well, not actually "slow", but the code is a lot more complex. This doesn't take an exclusive lock on the involved tables, though, so it's a lot cleaner and safer:

```
WITH RECURSIVE x AS (
    SELECT conrelid::regclass
    FROM   pg_constraint
    WHERE  confrelid = 'user_tbl'::regclass

    UNION
    SELECT p.conrelid::regclass
    FROM   x
    JOIN   pg_constraint p ON p.confrelid = x.conrelid
    )
SELECT conrelid::text AS tbl
FROM   x;
```

Returns:

```
tbl
------
tbl1
tbl2
tbl3
```

I use a [**recursive CTE**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html) (requires PostgreSQL 8.4 or later) on the catalog table [`pg_constraint`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/catalog-pg-constraint.html), because each table can have dependencies in turn.
Use `UNION`, not `UNION ALL` to avoid multiple evaluation of tables that might be linked with multiple foreign keys directly or indirectly.

Comment: @GregPallis: I added a bit on how to identify depending tables.

Comment: Thank you! This was enormously helpful, and I learned a huge amount about Postgres in working through it.