# Referential integrity list of tables for truncation

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, referential-integrity

I was wondering if there is a quick and efficient way to order tables in `PostgreSQL` so that, if I ran a `DELETE FROM <table_name>` they would all succeed without breaking referential integrity.

E.g. if the tables were `USER -->* ACCOUNT -->* TRANSACTION`, I want to delete first TRANSACTION, then ACCOUNT, then USER because any other order would break the foreign key relationships.

I have done this before with other DBs by querying system tables and building a referential integrity tree in memory of some scripting language.  But I was wondering if there is a quick(er) way to produce such a list.

Comment: The title says `truncate`, but the post itself says `delete` - which are you going to use?

Comment: does it matter ?  the end result is the same, wiping all the data and having an empty schema

Comment: I was kind of hoping you have FKs in place, so you could just do `TRUNCATE TABLE users CASCADE`, and leave postgres to worry about the order.

Comment: @amphibient: `DELETE` or `TRUNCATE` matters when talking about referential integrity. [Read the fine manual here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-truncate.html). Either way, you can find two different approaches to get the recursive tree of referenced tables [in this related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13099226/in-postgres-how-could-i-replace-all-tables-of-a-database-except-one-with-data/13099617#13099617).

Answer (score 0):

How about defining foreign keys that cascade deletes, so you do not need to do this?

Comment: this does not answer my question so it is more appropriate to be a comment

Comment: It answers the problem you have. You're asking for a manual methodology for a task that RDBMS suppliers have already automated.

Comment: @amphibient: Some more info and maybe a link to the manual would be nice, but it is the proper solution.

Comment: i am not the DBA.  i cannot change the schema.  i can delete data but cannot change schema.  i wish ppl here didn't make assumptions and adhered to what the question stipulates.

Comment: I wish that people would remember that Stackoverflow is not just here to answer their particular question, particularly when they have constraints on the way they can solve a problem that they do not list in the question. Remember that questions and answers are of most value when others can learn from them.